# Showing some fields depending on select list issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have form and i am showing the input field depending on the select list (if they select tow the input field tow will be showing ) and its work fine 
my problem is the text fields are rquired , so if they select one option then the other field related to other options will be hidden , the form is not submitting to database anymore because that hidden fields are required

what is the solution to solve it?

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<input ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text" required>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` rather than `ng-show`.

The former removes the field from the DOM, whereas the latter just applies a CSS rule hiding it.

Comment: can you tell me how to use it :)

Comment: The same way you're using ng-show. You could also read the documentation. It never hurts.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Post a plunkr containing a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem.